# How can I use the RPI3 to generate a sawtooth with frequency around 20kHz?

Tags: rpi.gpio, pi-3b+, pigpio

I am trying to generate a sawtooth waveform from the GPIO, the frequency is high, 20 Khz. is pigpio library my best option?

Comment: since gpio can be only in one of two states (high, low) ... how do you propose to generate a sawtooth?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistor_ladder

Comment: I wasn't planning to do it directly. May be use the resistor ladder or a CoTS DAC, thanks.

Comment: Still interested in this? Would you consider adding an external op amp? What about external Resistor and Capacitor? {Here are the basics for the RC approach](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_3.html); let us know if you need help.

Answer (score 2):

All the Raspberry's GPIO are binary, thus you can not directly generate a sawtooth wave.

With that being said, as the laconic [@jsotola's comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94093/how-can-i-use-the-rpi3-to-generate-a-sawtooth-with-frequency-around-20khz#comment152229_94093) suggested, you may use a resistor ladder to create a Digital to Analog circuit and connect it with your GPIO pins. You will then be able to use the GPIO pins like a counter to generate a staircase waveform, which may be sawtooth-like enough depending on you application, but this will demand an even higher GPIO write frequency with every additional GPIO pin you use.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best way to go. For time constraint, I am think to use a CoTs DAC. Do you recommend something?

Comment: No, sorry, but there are many arduino DAC boards that should be compatible with the raspberry. I would worry about meeting the frequency requirement (depends on the language and library you will use to control the GPIO).